# How to detect changing files in selected folder and selected file extension?

Tags: git, githooks

How to config git hook for detecting exactly selected folder (exem /../../schemas) and exactly selected file extension (exem *.xsd)?

Comment: What exaclty should your hook do? What have you tried?

Comment: I want just get name of changed file and author name. I want to automatically send email with this info to smbd. But I'll deal with sending email myself =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `git diff` to see all changes and grep results by the pattern you like. Like this

```
all_changes=$(git diff --cached --find-copies --find-renames --name-only --diff-filter=ACR)
only_xsd_files=$(echo $all_changes | grep "\.xsd")
only_schemas=$(echo $only_xsd_files | grep "path/to/schemas")
```

And then you can run rest of your script